# Lighthouse CLI: how to use current browser settings(running with extensions installed)

Tags: performance, lighthouse

Try lighthouse CLI to measure the performance of URLs with some extensions on.

With

```sh
lighthouse https://www.bing.com/search?q=curse+words --output json --output-path D:\lighthouseResults\0506.json --disable-device-emulation --chrome-flags="--user-agent=edge --window-size=360,640 --enable-experimental-extension-apis"
```

it doesn't seem that the extension was working(usually takes a few seconds, very slow), and did not find http requests that were suppose to be there in the report.

How should I do it in Lighthouse or I'm looking at the wrong tool?